# AWK + Host lookup

Tags: unix, host, awk

Currently using the following line to get top 20 ips sorted by requests:

```
grep 'GET /' /var/log/nginx/access.log | awk '{ print $1 }' | sort -n | uniq -c | sort -rn | head -20
```

Output:

```
575 66.249.*.*
570 66.249.*.*
534 207.46.*.*
511 157.55.*.*
493 66.249.*.*
435 207.46.*.*
383 66.249.*.*
378 157.55.*.*
368 66.249.*.*
336 66.249.*.*
334 188.165.*.*
332 174.24.*.*
292 54.209.*.*
251 66.249.*.*
241 66.249.*.*
234 66.249.*.*
226 66.249.*.*
225 89.145.*.*
221 89.145.*.*
209 66.249.*.*
```

I would like to lookup each ip using "host"

Is it possible to accomplish this in one line?

Thanks

Comment: No, because those aren't valid. How did you get the asterisks in there? I don't see anything obvious in your command line that would cause that.

Comment: @MichaelHampton IPs have been replaced with * for obvious reasons...

Comment: No, not obvious at all why you obfuscated Google's and Microsoft's addresses. It's not like nobody knows what they are!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
awk '/GET / {print $1}' /var/log/nginx/access.log | sort -n | uniq -c | \ 
sort -rn | head -20 | awk '{print $2}' | while read row; do host $row; done
```

I added a linebreak to make it more redably here.

I removed `grep` because you can filter with `awk` directly.

This piece of code: `awk '{print $2}' | while read row; do host $row; done` will execute the `host` command on every row (ip-address).

**EDIT**

This will keep the initial count and order:

```
awk '/GET / {print $1}' /var/log/nginx/access.log | sort -n | uniq -c | \ 
sort -rn | head -20 | while read row; do z=$( echo $row | awk '{print $2}' ); \
echo "$row $(host $z)"; done
```

It's not exactly a pretty solution but it does work.

Comment: Thanks! it's working. However, it is possible to add the hostname at the end of the ips and keep the initial count and order?

Comment: @Bastien I'm glad to here it works. I have tweaked the code a bit so it will keep the inital count and order. Try it out.

Answer (score 2):

Note that in general you should try to avoid superfluous DNS lookups because it can lead to capacity problems with DNS servers and may often prevent caching on the client (so can be much slower too). Use `getent hosts` to do the lookup.

I have an AWK example on my blog page http://distracted-it.blogspot.co.nz/2015/04/please-dont-use-dig-etc-in-reporting.html

Sample
Nice and script-friendly. Let's see how to pull that in AWK (or GAWK), with a simple example first. Let's start off with some input -- perhaps lines with an IP address and some count. I've also include a threshold, just as a reminder that it's good to minimise the number of lookups.

```
$ echo -e '1.1.1.1 2\n8.8.8.8 12\n8.8.4.4 25' \
  | awk '
    BEGIN {threshold = 5}
    $2 > threshold {
      "getent hosts " $1 | getline getent_hosts_str;
      split(getent_hosts_str, getent_hosts_arr, " ");
      print $1, getent_hosts_arr[2], $3
    }'
8.8.8.8 google-public-dns-a.google.com
8.8.4.4 google-public-dns-b.google.com
```